# How to display new rows without refresh using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm actually a little bit confused with all these AJAX techniques. The aim is to display the new rows on my site when new rows are inserted into my database, but i dont know how. The following code has been inserted into my Joomla site threw an extension:

```
<!-- You can place html anywhere within the source tags -->


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
// You can place JavaScript like this

</script>
<?php

$today = date("d/m/Y");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM queue WHERE";

$sql =$sql . " Date>='$today' ORDER BY Qnumber Desc LIMIT 3";

 // echo $sql;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","db","pass");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Αριθμός Εξυπηρέτησης</th>

<th>Πελάτες σε Αναμονή</th>
<th>Ώρα</th>

<th>Ημερομηνία</th>

</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Qnumber'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['WaitingCustomers'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['Time'] . "</td>";

  echo "<td>" . $row['Date'] . "</td>";

  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";

  mysqli_close($con);

  ?>
```

Comment: Have a GET variable to check whether the request is from Ajax or normal. And if it's Ajax request just print the rows excluding <table> tags and the header of the table. By header I mean the <th> tags. Use isset() function in php to check for the Ajax. For Ajax request, consider using jQuery. api.jquery.com/jquery.get

Comment: I think you mean, threw an exception.

Comment: Is this maybe what you are looking for? [link](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/site-navigation/24577) This extension automatically loads new rows in a category blog layout.